# Can use Azure Synapse and Azure Data Factory to transform and convert CSV to XML?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a concern about Azure Synapse and Azure Data Factory like this:
We using Azure Data lake gen 2 to export data from D365FO. After that, use Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse to transform (complex) and create a xml file.

My customer decided to use Azure Synapse to transform, but i checked, look like Azure Synapse only support to XML as Source, not Sink and doesn't support transform (flexiable like XSLT)?
You guys have any opinions about that? please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, XML format is only supported as a source in the Azure Data Factory and [not supported as sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml).
You can raise a feature request here.

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/